# Mysql - return keywords by search term based on max appearance in content

Tags: mysql, search, keyword

What I expect to do is:
when user search for any term, depending upon the content, sql query should return list of maximum occured words.

For example:

**Table schema:**
`tbl_product (id, title, content)`

**Search term:** `car`

**Expected output depending upon content:**

1. car (100)
2. cars (75)
3. card (50)
4. carpenter (20)
5. cargo (15)

**EDIT**

The main intention here is to return keywords matched by the expression.

Comment: Sorry @ajreal but I don't think its a duplicate. because what I want to return is not just the count of appearance but also the matched keywords as well. Can you please have a look at it once again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tb.carname FROM tbl_product tb WHERE tb.carname LIKE '%car%'
```

Comment: A code only answer is not high quality.   Please edit your answer to annotate your code, explain why and how it solves the problem, and link to any relevant documentation.